# Automating Quick Responses in WhatsApp Group

Tags: whatsapp

I'd like to send an automatic message (always the same one) when I receive a message containing certain words from a specific user in a what's app group.
What I want is for my message to be sent as quickly as possible.

I have no idea what resource I could use to do this, could you please point me in the right direction?